# Minecraft Download

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I downloaded Minecraft onto one of my laptops, but it's about to break since it's so old. I'll be getting a new laptop soon, but I was wondering if it's possible to download Minecraft onto my new laptop without having to buy a new account.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you can log in with your account on the Minecraft website ([link](https://minecraft.net/)), you will always be able to download the Minecraft launcher to play Minecraft